# Align Box (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css

How do I align the red box to the white box?

As you can see the red "box" is overlapping the border.

[image: Current Result]

Code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="box" id="media">
   etc etc ... etc etc<br>etc etc
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.box{
   background: white;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
   height: auto;
}

.box2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -99px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 100px 100vw 0 0;
    border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: The red box goes beyond the white box and out of context! I want to be aligned, the white one with the red one! (Check image)

Comment: The mix of CSS and inline styles is giving me a head ache. Why would you do that to yourself?

Answer (score -1):

You are using `100vw` in your border dimensions. That means 100% of the viewport.

You have not shared all relevant code so I cannot tell if you have padding on the container of these divs, but if you do you can change `100vw` to `100%` and the red triangle should respect the same padding as the white box.

Answer (score -2):

use ID in html file and style that ID in css file